# unrecognised selector error for AFHTTPRequestOperation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to run the following code in IOS.

```c
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [self.httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url.text]]
                                         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                           NSLog(@"reply data = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                         }
                                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                           NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                         }];
[requestOperation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:^BOOL(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace) {
  return YES;
}];
```

I then get an error like this:

> -[AFHTTPRequestOperation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75a81f0

As far as I can see the block that I'm passing has the correct return type and parameters. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the operation is null, and you didn't initialize it correctly?

Comment: I checked in the debugger and requestOperation is not null.

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperation is a subclass of AFURLConnectionOperation: "@interface AFHTTPRequestOperation : AFURLConnectionOperation"

Comment: That seems to be correct indeed. Removed comment to avoid confusion... Strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFURLRequestOperation conditionally compiles with certain delegate callback methods available, depending on whether `_AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_` is defined or not.

If it is (which is the default when installing from CocoaPods), `setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` will be available. Otherwise `setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:` and `setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` will be available.

`setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock` corresponds to `connection:willSendRequest:forAuthenticationChallenge:`, which is [the preferred delegate method to handle challenges](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).